# The last p digits of $p^p$ form a prime number,where p is a prime

Tags: prime-numbers

Let p be a prime number, here I'm interested with the last p digits of $p^p$ if it forms a prime number. And if I've not mistaken, the smallest p with that property is $433$. Meaning that the last $433$ digits of $433^{433}$ is a prime number. I have checked p up to $1999$ but I couldn't find anymore p with such property. Is there other p with that property ?

Comment: Two consecutive primes are $139$ and $149$. The number $143$ is not prime.

Comment: In fact, the smallest $p$ with the desired property is $433$

Comment: Upto $p=21000$ , there are $5$ numbers $p$ which lead to a prime of the desired form : $143,433,1687,3283,14949$. Of those numbers, only $433$ is prime.

Answer (score 2):

Of course this problem is base dependent.  In binary arithmetic $11$ (meaning three)  raised to its own power gives the last three bits $011$ which is a prime number.